# Bash - Multiple conditions in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I'm trying to do a for loop with multiple conditions and I didn't find any information about how to do it on the web

I'm sorry for the stupid questions, but I just started programming in  linux

what am I doing wrong here?

```
    #!/bin/bash

j=0

for line in `cat .temp_` || j in `seq 0 19`
do
    ...

done
```

the error says  wrong syntax and that I can't use ||

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for line in `cat .temp_`
do
    if ! grep -Fxq $line $dictionary && [ $j -lt 20 ]
    then
        echo $line >> $dictionary
        j=$((j+1))
    fi
    [ $j -gt 20 ] && break
done
```

You can't check a condition in a `for` loop in shell. You must do it in a extra statement.
In this case so:

```
[ $j -gt 20 ] && break
```

Another solution, without `break`:

```
while read line && [ $j -lt 20 ]
do
    if ! grep -Fxq $line $dictionary && [ $j -lt 20 ]
    then
        echo $line >> $dictionary
        j=$((j+1))
    fi
done < .temp_
```

Comment: ok thanks, but wouldn't that be O(n^2), like one for inside another? if this is what I'm asking the syntax looks just weird to me :O

Comment: sorry, I didn't catch the point at the first time; but now I did; I've rewritten the script.

Comment: kk, thanks a lot :) Isn't there a more elegant way without the break?

Comment: Why not? Added another solution :)

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to combine two different styles of `for`-loops into one. Instead, just break if the value of `j` becomes too large:

```
j=0
while read -r line; do
    [[ j >= 20 ]] && break
    ...
done < ._temp
```

(This, by the way, is the preferred way to iterate over a file in bash. Using a `for`-loop runs into problems if the file is too large, as you essentially building a command line using the entire contents of the file.)

[UPDATE: the following is based on my conjecture as to the purpose of the loop. See [Calculate Word occurrences from file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850823/calculate-word-occurrences-from-file-in-bash) for the real context.]

Actually, you can dispense with the loop. You are looking for at most 20 lines from .temp_ that do not already appear in the file whose name is in dictionary, right?

```
sort -u .temp_ | grep -f $dictionary -Fx -v -m 20 >> $dictionary
```

This will call `grep` just once, instead of once per line in `.temp_`.

Comment: The last solution (with sort -u and head) is incorrect. It can make wrong result if you have unsorted lines in .temp_

Comment: Right. I realized there was a possibility for duplicates in the output, but didn't think through the best way to eliminate them. I'll update.

Comment: that is better, but now you lose the order of lines in `.temp_`. May be you could write both variants and explain the difference between them? (anyway +1)

Comment: Given Epi's more recent question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850823/calculate-word-occurrences-from-file-in-bash), I'm going to stop second-guessing the loop :)

Comment: @chepner: wow, I haven't seen this question yet. Looks pretty interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested for-loop?

```
for line in `cat file`; do for j in {0..19}; do
     your_commands
done; done
```

If I understand you correctly (you want to run a command on every line 20 times).

Comment: nope not nested I just want to break the while after 20 times

Comment: Oh, now understand the other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I need to process all files inside a directory, but only until nth file or until all is processed:

```
count=1
nth=10
for f in folder/*; do
  ((count++))
  # process $f
  if [[ $count -gt $nth ]] 
  then
    break
  fi
done
```