# Calculate Word occurrences from file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, uniq

I'm sorry for the very noob question, but I'm kind of new to `bash` programming (started a few days ago). Basically what I want to do is keep one file with all the word occurrences of another file

I know I can do this:

```
sort | uniq -c | sort
```

the thing is that after that I want to take a second file, calculate the occurrences again and update the first one. After I take a third file and so on.

What I'm doing at the moment works without any problem (I'm using `grep`, `sed` and `awk`), but it looks pretty slow.

I'm pretty sure there is a very efficient way just with a command or so, using `uniq`, but I can't figure out.

Could you please lead me to the right way?

I'm also pasting the code I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
#   count the number of word occurrences from a file and writes to another file #
#   the words are listed from the most frequent to the less one                 #

touch .check                # used to check the occurrances. Temporary file
touch distribution.txt      # final file with all the occurrences calculated

page=$1             # contains the file I'm calculating
occurrences=$2          # temporary file for the occurrences

# takes all the words from the file $page and orders them by occurrences
cat $page | tr -cs A-Za-z\' '\n'| tr A-Z a-z > .check

# loop to update the old file with the new information
# basically what I do is check word by word and add them to the old file as an update
cat .check | while read words
do
    word=${words}       # word I'm calculating
    strlen=${#word}     # word's length
    # I use a black list to not calculate banned words (for example very small ones or inunfluent words, like articles and prepositions
    if ! grep -Fxq $word .blacklist && [ $strlen -gt 2 ]
    then
        # if the word was never found before it writes it with 1 occurrence
        if [ `egrep -c -i "^$word: " $occurrences` -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "$word: 1" | cat >> $occurrences
        # else it calculates the occurrences
        else
            old=`awk -v words=$word -F": " '$1==words { print $2 }' $occurrences`
            let "new=old+1"
            sed -i "s/^$word: $old$/$word: $new/g" $occurrences
        fi
    fi
done

rm .check

# finally it orders the words
awk -F": " '{print $2" "$1}' $occurrences | sort -rn | awk -F" " '{print $2": "$1}' > distribution.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure that I've got the point of the thing you are trying to do, 
but I would do it this way:

```
while read file
do
  cat $file | tr -cs A-Za-z\' '\n'| tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c > stat.$file
done < file-list
```

Now you have statistics for all your file, and now you simple aggregate it:

```
while read file
do
  cat stat.$file
done < file-list \
| sort -k2 \
| awk '{if ($2!=prev) {print s" "prev; s=0;}s+=$1;prev=$2;}END{print s" "prev;}'
```

Example of usage:

```
$ for i in ls bash cp; do man $i > $i.txt ; done
$ cat <<EOF > file-list
> ls.txt
> bash.txt
> cp.txt
> EOF

$ while read file; do
> cat $file | tr -cs A-Za-z\' '\n'| tr A-Z a-z | sort | uniq -c > stat.$file
> done < file-list

$ while read file
> do
>   cat stat.$file
> done < file-list \
> | sort -k2 \
> | awk '{if ($2!=prev) {print s" "prev; s=0;}s+=$1;prev=$2;}END{print s" "prev;}' | sort -rn | head

3875 the
1671 is
1137 to
1118 a
1072 of
793 if
744 and
533 command
514 in
507 shell
```

Comment: Epi, I was glad to help you :)