# command to count occurrences of word in entire file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to count the occurrences of a word in a file.

If word occurs multiple times in a line, I will count is a 1.

Following command will give me the output but will fail if line has multiple occurrences of word

```
grep -c "word" filename.txt
```

Is there any one liner?

Comment: possible duplicate [Calculate Word occurrences from file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850823/calculate-word-occurrences-from-file-in-bash)

Comment: Does "I will count is a 1." mean "I will count it as 1" or "I will count each as 1" ?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `grep -o` to show the exact matches and then count them:

```
grep -o "word" filename.txt | wc -l
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello hello how are you
hello i am fine
but
this is another hello

$ grep -c "hello" a    # Normal `grep -c` fails
3

$ grep -o "hello" a 
hello
hello
hello
hello
$ grep -o "hello" a | wc -l   # grep -o solves it!
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Set RS in awk for a shorter one.

```
awk 'END{print NR-1}' RS="word" file
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk allows it to be done in single command with use of multiple piped commands:

```
awk -v w="word" '$1==w{n++} END{print n}' RS=' |\n' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | cut -d ' ' | grep -c word
```

This assumes that all words in the file have spaces between the words. If there's punctuation concatenating the word to itself, or otherwise  no spaces on a single line between the word and itself, they'll count as one.

Comment: how about `tr " " "\n"< file |grep -c "word"`

Comment: I think `grep -o '[^ \t\n,.]\+'`would let you specify word separators, then use `wc -l`

Comment: Sorry, missed the -P option in the regexp. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix for more info

Answer (score -1):

```
grep word filename.txt | wc -l
```

`grep` prints the lines that match, then `wc -l` prints the number of lines matched

Comment: It does not count reoccurrences of words in the same line. This counts how many lines have the word in them

Comment: @GuntramBlohm No it does not. Given my sample file, it would return 3 instead of 4.

Comment: "I will count is a 1." would mean, to me, he wants multiple words on the same line count only once.

Comment: However, read the "Following command will give me the output but will fail if line has multiple occurrences of word." I think he probably meant to say "If a word occurs multiple times in a line, it will count it as 1"

Comment: yes, he meant that "up to now, if multiple occurence on one line it counts it as one" and therefor he is looking for a better solution (one that counts occurence of the word, not of lines containing the word) (hence the question. Otherwise, his "grep -c" would already be the answer).