# how to count a particular word in text fie using bash file

Tags: bash

I have a text file which contains texts as below:

```
ITEM
preset_date 23/10/15
preset_time 22:00:00:00
title Buletin Awani Headlines
clip TAPE_REPLACEMENT
in_src 0
out_src 1500
mode 2
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 1
user_data 08_P_152784839
logo_data_0 0
channel_id 2
end
ITEM
preset_date 23/10/15
preset_time 22:01:00:00
title Episode Number 7
clip HJNAW01HM01AA
in_src 902250
out_src 915700
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 1
user_data 08_P_152784840
logo_data_0 0
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 1
subtitle HJNAW01HM01
end
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of the word `logo` in the file. How do I want to achieve this using Bash file? Appreciate your assistance ..

Comment: How would you filter lines that contain a word from a file?

Comment: Look into `man grep`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [command to count occurrences of word in entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603555/command-to-count-occurrences-of-word-in-entire-file)

Comment: @uzairi: You need to define what exactly you consider to be a "word".  For instance, if the file contains the string `xlogoylogoz`, does this count as zero, 1 or two occurances of the  _logo_?

Comment: If the word occurs multiple times in a line, I will count is a 1.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -c 'logo' < input file name`

Comment: While this would work for the concrete example posted, it would fail if the word _logo_ occurs several times in a line.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count=0
match="logo" # note: this is a regular expression

while read -a line ; do
    for word in "${line[@]}" ; do
        [[ $word =~ $match ]] && let 'count=count+1'
    done
done

echo $count
```

---

### Instructions for how to run

Save the script into `count_logo.sh`.  Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x count_logo.sh
```

Run the script with input from your text file (say `file.txt`) using:

```
./count_logo.sh < file.txt
```

Comment: how do i link with the .txt file in directory folder?

Comment: Put the script into a file, say `count_logo.sh`.  Make the script executable using `chmod +x count_logo.sh`.  Finally run the script with input from your text file (say `file.txt`) using `./count_logo.sh < file.txt`.

Comment: the script will save as .bat file?

Comment: @uzairi I suggest naming it `count_logo.sh` in my example.  Have a look at **Instructions for how to run**.

Comment: is this executable in windows?

Comment: If you have and are running `bash` on windows, you may have to run it like this: `bash count_logo.sh < file.txt`